# Не работает команда IF в пакетном файле

Tags: bat

Я неплохо разбираюсь в пакетных файлах, но при написании IF в любом мести этой программы у меня этот IF игнорировался программой.
Вот код:

```
@echo off
set ro=1
:rr
echo %ro%
ping -n 1 -w 500 202.311.21.012>nul
set /a ro=%ro%+1
pause
if %ro% GTR 2 set %ro%=1
goto rr
```

Comment: Что делает эта ваша программа?

Comment: Глеб, эта программа задумана как генератор случайных чисел, которым она пока что не является. Я добавил туда ```pause```, чтобы она не закрывалась сразу же после запуска.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` у тебя работает
у тебя не работает `set`, потому что он неправильный
правильный будет вот такой: `set ro=1`

Comment: Да вроде там есть такой set

Comment: @CrazyElf - у него `set %ro%=1`

Comment: А, теперь увидел где. Лучше бы вы привели целиком строчку, я вот не понял о чём речь )